# Compile c# project with csc command

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core, csc

I have a .net 4.6.1 project (with the new csproj format)  that references a netstandard2.0 project. 
When building this project **i get errors in the output but not in the UI or error list of visual studio 2017** (version 15.4.3).

the error listed in the output is

```
 The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace
```

I built the project with `msbuild /bl` and used [structured log viewer](http://msbuildlog.com/)
to see the actual command that was used to compile the project.
The command is very long (25000+ characters)
I placed this command in a bat file and running it returned :

```
 error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\SystemDiagnostics.StackTrace.dll' could not be found

error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Runime.dll' could not be found

error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v46.1\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll' could not be found
```

those libraries are referenced  via the `/reference` csc argument but the error in the output has a slightly mangled name:

> **SystemDiagnostics.StackTrace.dll** instead of
>   System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
>
> **System.Runime.dll** instead of System.Runtime.dll
>
> .NETFramework\v46.1\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll instead
>   of .NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll

Why does csc try to find those wrong mangled names instead of the actually referenced dlls ?

*PS*: The netstandard2.0 dll that contains the `Services` namespace is missing in the `/refferences` of the long csc command.

Comment: Those mangled names are funny, have you searched for them in your batch and project files? They have to come from somewhere.

Comment: @Henk Holterman yes , the correct names are referenced . I think I will open an issue at `msbuild` for the missing reference in csc and mention this question

Comment: Something is eating a character occasionally.  The IDE talks to MSBuild using a named pipe.  Named pipes are often the victim of the kind of shrink-wrapped shovelware that programmers voluntarily install on their machines.  Disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: @HansPassant  I am getting the mangled names when runninf the `bat` (that contains the cmd line) , not in the IDE . But you may be right , I also remember debugging not working in VS due to corporate Symantec antivirus installed (disabling the Antivirus worked).  I am investigating now running the cmd with powershell but i deed to delimit the parameters...

Comment: @HansPassant it seams to be working with powershell , I get the same namespace errors as msbuild. Adding the dependent project  netstandard2.0 project dll reference in the cmdline produces compiles!!. But produces only the obj's and an empty bin/debug/net461  ..... (the referenced .netstd2.0 project has wanings of 'this package may not be fully compatible with your project' )

Comment: You could create a binary log using the `/bl` argument to msbuild and inspect the items passed to the various tasks (using the [structured log viewer](http://msbuildlog.com))